# How to Stop Ms Sql from auto sorting while inserting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

When I insert any data into my table bus_id automatically get sorted alphabetically. I wish to view them by the order in which they were inserted because my bus_id is varchar which I made combined with integer and string. So sorting them would jumble up.

The code I use to generate bus_id column

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(bus_id) from bus_details", con);


int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
  con.Close();
  i++;
  lblbusid.Text = busID + i.ToString();
```

And pass the data to the table

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into bus_details (bus_id,bcompany_id, bus_type,capacity) values(@bus_id,@bcompany_id, @bus_type,@capacity)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bus_id", lblbusid.Text);
```

[How data displayed to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWjl5.png)

Comment: SQL Server doesn't "auto sort". There's no sort order when you read data either, unless you *specify one* with `ORDER BY`.

Comment: if `bus_id` is the primary key, it will be sorted by this column. You can change the order using `order by` as @PanagiotisKanavos pointed

Comment: BTW using a count to generate any kind of ID is guaranteed to create duplicates if even one entry is deleted. Use an IDENTITY constrained, a SEQUENCE if you want incrementing IDs

Comment: SQL does not guarantee an order without an ORDER BY. Your IDs are going to cause you problems even with an ORDER BY the way you're currently producing them.

Comment: @RicardoPontual only by accident. It *may* be stored in that order, if it's also a clustered index. The server though can return data in any order if `ORDER BY` isn't specified. Parallelism, joins, spooling to tempdb can change the order rows are processed and how they are emitted to the client

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what I've meant was that, if you execute a `select` command, without `order by` clause, the data will be returned, **if you have a primary key** defined, ordered by the primary key column

Comment: @Ricardo absolutely not. It will likely return the data in that order until the plan changes. See the link I posted above, it debunks that myth 100%. And it is the clustered index, not the primary key that makes this behavior appear to function that way.

Comment: @RicardoPontual I already explained why it won't, even if the primary key is also a clustered index. A primary key *doesn't have to* be the clustered index, if some other storage order makes more sense. All you need is to add a parallel hint to a query to see the rows returned in random order

Comment: @RicardoPontual oh, and it would have to be stored in a *single* disk too. If the data was stored in a RAID array the retrieval order could be different.

Comment: wow very interesting reading, thanks for sharing @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Ricardo No, there is no guarantee that data will be returned ordered by the primary key column. This is the point everyone has been trying to make. See [#3 on this post](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/).

Comment: Sometimes I wish the optimizer by default used a built-in random number generator to explicitly return the rows in that order whenever someone issues a `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY`, just to hammer home this point, unless you add `OPTION (I_UNDERSTAND_TABLES_ARE_NOT_ORDERED)`, when it reverts back to giving you the rows as fast as possible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Really, you wish the optimizer would slow down execution.

Comment: If my answer below helped, please upvote with the up arrow next to the answer. If it gave you the answer to your question, please accept the answer by pressing the tick. This will increase your reputation and help other people who visit your question in future. If it didn't help please add a comment to clarify why not.

Answer (score 0):

So to summarise, before I give the answer the OP was looking for and some bonus tips...

1. SQL will physically store rows in an order indicated by a key or index being clustered, and you can define what that thing is.
2. SQL will give you back whatever records your query asked for as fast as it can, based on your query but you should not infer that the order it gives you records back is related to the order they are stored.
3. If you haven't specified an order, it has the right to return the records in **any** order, and what most people don't realise is that it may return records for an unchanged query in a different order after a period of time, when it becomes more efficient to retrieve them a different way. So if you care about the order, you must specify the order by clause, even if they already seem to be coming out in the order you want.
4. SQL server can help you uniquely identify a row. Use an IDENTITY column, rather than reinvent the wheel yourself, as there are plenty of pitfalls.

The answer to the question is to add this clause on the end of the select query... "Order by serial".

Other tips...

- SqlCommand and SqlConnection are disposable so put them in `using` blocks.
- I suggest you [stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) before it causes you problems.